# MS Excel 2010 Automatic calculation of formulas doesn't hold.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Once I have set formula workbook calculations to "Manual". Now I set it back to "automatic" but excel  won't hold that selection after I close the file. The next time I open a file it comes set to "manual" again.

Does anybody have the such a problem, and solution to that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed it in the settings: File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic ?

Comment: Yes I change it and save the file afterwards and exit. Next time I open excel it comes manual again.